# Can't open .py fileon cmd when working directory folder and path is set

Tags: command-line, pycharm

Following is the output from the CMD. Receiving [Errno 2]. Notice a.py is in the folder with python.exe and i am able to launch python through py command.

```
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36>a.py
C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe: can't open file '#': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is x

 Directory of C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

04/02/2018  06:46 PM    <DIR>          .
04/02/2018  06:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/01/2018  07:30 PM               600 a.py

12/23/2016  08:09 AM           100,504 python.exe
12/23/2016  08:06 AM            52,888 python3.dll
12/23/2016  08:06 AM         3,555,992 python36.dll
12/23/2016  08:09 AM            98,968 pythonw.exe
12/23/2016  07:10 AM             8,434 README.txt

C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36>py
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run like this

```
python.exe a.py
```

or if path is set correctly,

```
python a.py
```

Comment: Just created a User variable to python.exe and im now able to open the file on the same folder but i cannot when in desktop..